# group by and aggregate in django

Tags: sql, django, group-by

I want to select in django from database.

Test have many tests results.

I need to select the latest ending.

in SQl I would use

```
select *,max(timeEnd) from testresult group by idTest
```

and receive a good answer how can i make something alike in django

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation is relatively simple in Django.  Here is the documentation on the topic:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/

To achieve your query in Django, you'd probably write something like:

```
from django.db.models import Max
TestResult.objects.values('idTest').annotate(Max('timeEnd'))
```

Comment: but aggregation function gets the value, i need the element

Comment: Just takes out the .values() part, and it return objects: `TestResult.objects.annotate(Max('timeEnd'))`

Comment: but without the values part, how do you define the group by

Answer (score 0):

You could even use raw sql if it is becoming more complex check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#topics-db-sql)